# jQuery time and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am looking for a time output using jQuery, for example, would be great to know what time it is on the visitor's browser and the current day (friday,saturday,monday, etc...).

Is there any way to do it only with jQuery? I don't really like the way javascript handles time issues.

If you recommend any plugin, please tell me wich.

Thanks so much!
Souza.

EDIT:

I'm looking to avoid substring javascript outputs, or convert the results.

Wouldn't be great to use

```
$("#setime").yourtime("day");
```

and give me the day?
or

```
 $("#setime").yourtime("hour", 24format);
```

and give you the hour in any format you need?

?

Comment: Well, of course it's written in javascript, it's why it's called a library
Do you use javascript to work with animations? Do you simplify your life by using jquery functions already done?

Wouldn't be great to use `$("#setime").yourtime("day");` and give me the day?
or 
 `$("#setime").yourtime("hour", 24format);`
?

Comment: it was not clear to me what you disliked. Now with your elaborations in your comment, I know what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```

It's not jQuery but it will do what you want.

You also have:

```
var month = currentTime.getMonth()
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
```

To play with.

Comment: With this i will need to substring, convert, etc.

Comment: Yes. jQuery does not help you there.

Comment: Wouldn't be great to use `$("#setime").yourtime("day");` and give me the day?
or 
 `$("#setime").yourtime("hour", 24format);`
?

Comment: See my answer. I think that or similar is what you are looking for

Comment: You have a bunch of methods to play with there (see updates). You will definitely be able to do what is needed with what's here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you were looking for?

http://crossbreeze.github.com/jquery-sensible-datetime/

Download here: https://github.com/crossbreeze/jquery-sensible-datetime

If not, here is plain JS for you to reuse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var weekday=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"," Saturday"];
var monthname=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
function formatDate(d) {
  var text = "";
  text += weekday[d.getDay()] + " ";
  text += d.getDate() + " ";
  text += monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ";
  text += d.getFullYear();
  var hh = d.getHours();
  var mm = d.getMinutes();
  if (hh<10) hh = "0"+hh;
  if (mm<10) mm = "0"+mm;
  return text +" "+hh+":"+mm; 
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  var d = new Date();
  $("#dateDiv").text(formatDate(d));
});
</script>
```